# WordPress Custom Post Type Admin Search Doesn't Work

Tags: wordpress, search, admin, custom-post-type

I've created a custom post type in WordPress and it's all working great except the search functionality of it pulls zero results. And the weirder thing, is that if I hit search a second time, it'll pull me into the default post section of WordPress.

It's very odd and I haven't found anything online to resolve this.

Any ideas on how to create a working admin search from a CPT in the backend of WordPress?

Code

```
// Register custom function     
add_action( 'init', 'vendors', 0 );

// Create custom post-types 
function vendors() {
    register_post_type( 'vendors',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'               => 'Vendors',
            'singular_name'      => 'Vendor',
            'add_new'            => 'Add New',
            'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Vendor',
            'edit'               => 'Edit',
            'edit_item'          => 'Edit Vendor',
            'new_item'           => 'New Vendor',
            'view'               => 'View',
            'view_item'          => 'View Vendors',
            'search_items'       => 'Search Vendors',
            'not_found'          => 'No Vendors found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Vendors found in Trash',
            'parent'             => 'Parent Vendor'
        ),

        'public'                 => true,
        'menu_position'          => 15,
        'supports'               => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
        'menu_icon'              => '',
        'has_archive'            => true
    )
);
}
```

Comment: can you provide a code of you register_post_type function?

Comment: Not a solution but make sure you read [Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments)

Comment: it's work fine for me. May be problem not in CPT? Try to add your CPT on clear wordpress

Comment: can you provide the url with get params after search?

Comment: @VictorBredihin I searched 'keytech'  and got this url, no results. http://pickeringmarkets.com/stage/wp-admin/edit.php?s=keytech&post_status=all&post_type=vendors&action=-1&m=0&paged=1&mode=list&action2=-1

Comment: It's correct url, problem not in CPT, try to debug your code, disable one by one your plugins, enable default theme. I think problem may be in filters or hooks

Comment: I disabled all my plugins and I still was unable to get it working.

Comment: you want this cpt post not display when search the post? or your cpt not display in admin so just see the code hear http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/03/07/wordpress-custom-post-type/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my functions.php file. I had to remove each line one by one until I got the search working.